# iPad orientation split view

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation

Edit: Please download the sample xcode project and follow steps.
1. In iPad we have a splitview as a initial view controller.

1. In portrait mode click the blue button. You will see split view controller.
2. Go to "Item 2" tab and click the red button.
3. It opens login view. Login screen comes over to splitview. No problem here.
4. Rotate the iPad to landscape then login view is disappering. The split view is seen.

You can download the sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwsvBUWwFmkORXNUaVhiVVUzSjg/edit?usp=sharing)

Why the login view is disappearing? How can we prevent it to disappear. In portrait mode there is no problem.

Comment: Have you implemented custom code to handle rotation in either of these two view controllers ?

Comment: No. This problem occurs only in portrait mode when we rotate the iPad to landscape. In iphone there is no problem. It is about split view I think but can not find a solution.